# PHP Login Form. Always wrong email, password

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm having a little problem. I don't really know what I did wrong. I changed my Code from the deprecated php5 to php7 but after it. The Login doesnt work, as it should be

```
if(isset($_POST['is_login'])){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["USERS"]." WHERE `email` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."' AND `password` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password'])."'";
    $sql_result = mysqli_query ($connection,$sql) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
    $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_result);
    if(!empty($user)){
        $_SESSION['panel'] = $user;
        $query = " UPDATE ".$SETTINGS["USERS"]." SET last_login = NOW() WHERE id=".$user['id'];
        mysqli_query ($connection,$query ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$query);
    }
    else{
  $error = 'Wrong email or password.';
```

The last Statement `$error = 'Wrong email or password.';` is always being called. Thanks for help.

Comment: Escaping a password? No password encryption / hashing?

Comment: Not yet no, but this doesn't answer my question mate. Thanks

Comment: I think it was quite a clear point into the right direction. The issue lies within the fact that you're escaping input and not encrypting / hashing your passwords

Comment: Nope mate it doesnt. I was working perfectly fine when using php5

Comment: Yes. PHP5 != PHP7. That's pretty obvious. Why don't you use [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead? It'll make this a whole lot easier for you and it'll clean up your code as well. I would even advise to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of MySQLi because it supports more databases and is easier to work with.

Comment: Please format your code and make sure it's valid. If someone tries to help you by running it themselves, they shouldn't have to add to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `mysqli_real_escape_string()` requires a database connection be passed as the first argument.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Better than that, use a prepared statement and do away with those pesky function/db calls.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Do keep in mind that if you intend on going live with this or are live, then use a safe hashing method such as `password_hash()`. I'm sure you'll like to keep your database intact.

- `password_hash()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Debugging:

Using `mysqli_error()` on the query would have helped you during your transition.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error-list.php

Bit of a side note: if and when you decide to safely store passwords, remember to not use any escaping methods against passwords. One such as this `123'\abc<BR>` would be considered as being valid. But by escaping it, that would be interpreted as `123\'\abc<BR>` in turn rendering your verification method for it "null & void", and would fail silently because of it embedding the slash/escape quote in the hash. Both `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` take that into account.

- `password_verify()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: Thanks. Could you update your answer. Outlining what needs to be changed, using my code. Thanks

Comment: @floreich Please see the manuals and its syntax. You won't learn anything from all of this and writing it all out, it doesn't take that long. Are you in that much of a hurry?

Comment: Thanks, mate. I passed the $connection parameter. Now it works fine. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome @floreich and I'm glad you did this by yourself. I hope you're happy that you actually did fix this yourself, I applaud that, *cheers*.

Comment: @floreich Bit of a side note: if and when you decide to safely store passwords, remember to not use any escaping methods against passwords. One such as this `123'\abc<BR>` would be considered as being valid. But by escaping it, that would be interpreted as `123\'\abc<BR>` in turn rendering your verification method for it, would fail silently because of it embedding the slash/escape quote. Both `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` take that into account. (I'll add this to my answer also for future readers).